# Vaadin24 change the way timestamps are rendered in a grid

Tags: vaadin24

I want to display timestamps in a grid, but i do not like the default settings. How to set a custom renderer where i can specify the format in a vaadin 24 app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example, with a simple String format and a specific locale:

```
        grid.addColumn(new LocalDateRenderer<>(item -> item.getDate(), "MMM-dd-yyyy", Locale.GERMANY));
```

There are many other `LocalDateRenderer` constructors which allow you to use different ways of date formatting.

If your data type is something else than a `java.time.LocalDate`, just convert the value to a `LocalDate` first in the value provider (first constructor parameter).

Comment: What would you say to the solution i found?:
articlesGrid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(article ->
                {                                        Div div2 = new Div();
                                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    
                    String formattedTimestamp = sdf.format(article.getCreated());
                    div2.setText(formattedTimestamp);
                    return div2;
                })).

Comment: Using a component is less efficient than using a specialized Renderer.

Comment: Alright i will go with your solution. Efficiency is always good to have.